# Hakyll not updating with new routes

Tags: haskell, routes, hakyll

I'm trying to use Hakyll for the first time. Following the tutorials on [the official site](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/03-rules-routes-compilers.html), I'm trying to extend the route handling images to work with fonts. I've changed the code in `site.hs` to this:

```
match ("images/*" .||. "fonts/*") $ do
     route idRoute
     compile copyFileCompiler
```

In the `fonts` directory, I've got a number of `.ttf` font files whose permissions and owners match the rest of the site's static files (all of which work properly).

For some reason though, after rebuilding the site (with `stack exec site rebuild`), these updates aren't reflected in the binary, and routes to `fonts/*` result in a 404.

How can I get Hakyll to load fonts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stack exec site rebuild` rebuilds only the site data (the files generated inside the destination directory, `_site` by default). Whenever you change your site source, you will need to issue `stack build`.

If you were running the `watch` server, restart it – `stack build` creates a new `site` executable, it will not restart old running instances.

If you only added new rules, executing `site rebuild` after the `site` was built should not be needed, `site build` or `site watch` should notice that the files are missing in the ‘cache’. If you modified existing rules, however, you will need to let Hakyll know the files are no longer up to date. Cleaning the site using `site clean` or `site rebuild` will force the Hakyll to re-generate everything. When you have large site and only few files affected by the change, you can also re-save them or change their modification time (e.g. using `touch` command) to save time.

Comment: If I have `stack exec site watch` running, do I still need to `build/rebuild`, and do I need to restart `watch`?

Comment: I extended the answer.